# Best way to store files on a large scale enterprise level application

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core-2.1, core-api

I have a question on **Azure environment setup and file storage**.

We are currently developing a CRM as part of a large scale project. Currently, the CRM is reading a mailbox and creating tickets in the system from those emails. There could be around **5000 - 10,000** (could be more overtime) emails coming through everyday and will contain attachments.
At the moment I'm just using a folder on the application root path to store all the attachments plus any images on the email body.

The application is hosted on **Azure AppServices**.

My question is, is this the best way to store all these files, images, video files, etc.. or should I really consider storing them on blob storage or some other third part storage solution?

Comment: If you scale out your service to more than a single instance, how do you plan to access the attachments stored in the other instance's root path?

Comment: @John yeah,you are correct. I'm gonna change the storage to the Blog storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to note about Azure App Service is each tier (Shared, Basic, Standard ...) has a storage quota.
If you are storing your files on a root path (wwwroot), you will reach your quota soon and your application will stop.

You have to change that to move your files into Azure Blob Storage.

You can decide the storage tier (Hot vs Cold) depending on how frequently you access these files (that is a cost thing)

If you need these files on-premise then maybe you can use Azure Files instead of Blob Storage.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the answer. I guess I'll go with the Blob storage

Comment: You don't *have* to use blob storage. There are other solutions. Also, cold storage is likely very impractical for a live system. You can store metadata in one of many database options, along with blob storage (how you use them, and which database, is totally up to you and your needs). Also: Azure Files, while interesting to discuss in terms of on-premises usage, cannot be mounted from a Web App - you'd need to rely on the API Unfortunately, the original question is far too broad to provide a single objective answer.